# Combining two or more probabilities

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, scoring-algorithm

I'm trying to simplify a win/loss simulation. The situation is as follows:

Let's say there are two players A and B where:

- When A goes into a battle, it's probability of a win is 0.1 (10%)
- When B goes into a battle, it's probability of a win is 0.2 (20%)

**Note 1** : The win probability is invariant to the opponent.

**Note 2** : There are no draws, though there could be in a future enhancement, for now trying to keep things simple.

**Note 3** : There are other players in the game each with their own probabilities.

If A and B were to battle each other I need to determine who will win.

Currently what I'm doing is sampling 2 different Bernoulli distributions, one for A (with $P_a = 0.1$) and one for B (with $P_b = 0.2$)

I sample each of the distributions until ***only*** one of them returns success. That player is the winner of the battle, the other player will have *lost*. The following is pseudo code of the process:

```
while (true)
{
   bool win_a = bernoulli(pr_a);
   bool win_b = bernoulli(pr_b);

   if (win_a == win_b) // either both won or both lost
      continue;

   if (win_a)
      return "A won";
   else
      return "B won";
}
```

The problem with the above approach is that even though it will eventually determine a winner, it may end-up looping for a long time before it does.

I was wondering if there's a mathematically valid way of combining the above probabilities into a singular Bernoulli trial such that $Pr(A_{winning})= k$ and $Pr(B_{winning}) = 1 - k$ for some particular **k**.

My current thinking is that $k = \frac{P_a}{(P_a + P_b)}$ but I'm not sure if it is correct or how to reason about it correctness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=1$ if A wins and $0$ otherwise. 
Let $Y=1$ if B wins and $0$ otherwise.

$P(\text{A wins})=P(X=1,Y=0)=P(X=1)P(Y=0)=P_a(1-P_b)$

$P(\text{B wins})=P(X=0,Y=1)=P(X=0)P(Y=1)=P_b(1-P_a)$

So you need to generate a Bernoulli r.v. $Z$ with odds ratio $P_a(1-P_b):P_b(1-P_a)$

$P(\text{A wins})=P(Z=1)=\frac{P_a(1-P_b)}{P_a(1-P_b)+P_b(1-P_a)}$

$P(\text{B wins})=P(Z=0)=\frac{P_b(1-P_a)}{P_a(1-P_b)+P_b(1-P_a)}$

Comment: Ahhh now I understand!  thank-you for the explanation. So the simulation I'm running is generally wrong... yet seems to give what looks like "reasonable" results. I guess it's time to throw that away.

Comment: The simulation is right. It is called acceptance-rejection method. Thowing away the ties is equivalent to conditioning on a decisive result, which gives you exactly the probabilities above.

Comment: @JacobiJohn: I would not say your simulation is wrong.  I would say it is a heuristic that gives reasonable results.  There is not enough information to say whether a particular formula is right or wrong.

Comment: @Brian Tung I wouldn't exactly call it "heuristic". It just assumes independence. And it is a good model when the two Bernoulli are either independent or weakly conditioned.

Comment: When two contestants go head to head, I wouldn't generally assume independence.  In general, their winning probabilities aren't mutually consistent.

Comment: @momo: One further clarification, When you mention "generate a Bernoulli r.v. Z..."  For example do you mean that: win_a = Bernoulli($p_a(1-P_b)$);  -  if so is it possible to have an expression where i only need to sample a Bernoulli distribution once rather than sample-reject until the assumed condition occurs?  as I'm trying to remove the inefficicney related to the loop.

Comment: @Jacobi John Yes, this was my point. A wins is Bernoulli$\left(\frac{P_a(1-P_b)}{P_a(1-P_b)+P_b(1-P_a)}\right)$ You generate an uniform rv (using rnd) and you compare it with $\frac{P_a(1-P_b)}{P_a(1-P_b)+P_b(1-P_a)}$. If it is smaller you say that A wins, otherwise you say that B wins. You may also pre-calculate those values for different pairs of opponents, in order to further save time.

Comment: @momo I'm still tripping on the fact that the two identities aren't complimentary, I think i need to think more about in order to understand it,  but thank-you for the very detailed answer and set of explanations/comments!

Comment: @Brian Tung My impression is that OP wants to reduce the comptational effort for this uninformative model (which is the one used on betting sites). Otherwise, one might need to use some prior information, in order to infer more information about the probability of winning (stock market analysis software do that). But it doesn't seem to me that the OP is at that stage of his/her simulation.

Comment: @Jacobi John can you be more specific on each identities are not complementary?

Comment: @Momo: I agree.  I didn't intend for my cautionary note to start a long discussion; it's just a mild warning that there are some situations that don't fit the simple model.

Comment: I was trying to see if they were compliments of each other: Pa=1-Pb. I can't see how if Pb is moved onto the other side, things work out, however I went down a different path and think I made a mistake in the way I transposed the identities:  http://www.texpaste.com/n/bqp06ene

Comment: @Jacobi John you cancel out a $pq$ which has different signs. The easiest way is to see that the probabilities are of the form $\frac{x}{x+y}$ and $\frac{y}{x+y}$, which obviously add to $1$

Comment: You're absolutely right, I need some coffee - Thank-you for that! :D

Answer (score 1):

In sports simulations, there is a standard way to combine win probabilities for head-to-head contests in which no tie is possible, even when the contestants have not faced off previously.  It should be emphasized that this is heuristic *only*; there is no first-principles validation for this approach, because the situation is underdetermined.

Essentially, suppose that $A$'s winning probability is $p$, and $B$'s winning probability is $q$.  Then we write that

$$
P(\text{$A$ beats $B$}) = \frac{p(1-q)}{p(1-q)+q(1-p)}
$$

and

$$
P(\text{$B$ beats $A$}) = \frac{q(1-p)}{p(1-q)+q(1-p)}
$$

Your simulation happens to yield these same probabilities, but as I said, that's not provably correct.

Comment: thanks for the concise and informative answer, is there a name for the above formulation? something I further can research and read-up on, as I don't quite understand how those to identities were derived.

Comment: Why the simulation is not provably correct? I thought it is called acceptance-rejection method.

Comment: @Momo: Given the OP's methodology, it is provably correct.  What I mean is that there are plenty of situations where, on the whole, $A$'s winning percentage is $p$ and $B$'s winning percentage is $q$, but $A$ always beats $B$.  This approach assumes a kind of independence that we can't necessarily insist on.

Comment: @Momo: For instance, in a three-person round-robin, suppose $A$ always beats $B$, who always beats $C$, who always beats $A$ (cyclic dominance).  Then each player has a winning probability of $0.5$, but $A$ always beats $B$, even though the formula generates a winning probability of $0.5$ for any contestant in any contest.

Comment: @JacobiJohn: I'm not aware of a specific name; acceptance-rejection, cited by Momo, seems as good as any.  The origin of the expression is relatively straightforward: As in your simulation, we consider only those cases where one contestant wins and the other loses.  Within that restricted sample space (represented by the denominator in the expressions above), the probability of either contestant winning is the product of that contestant's winning probability and the opponent's losing probability.

Comment: I now I understand that aspect of it, I'm just having difficulty trying to wrap my head around the apparent lack of mutual exclusion, i would have thought that given the constraints that P(A wins) = 1 - P(B wins), but that doesn't seem to be the case for the identities above.

Comment: @JacobiJohn: No, the two probabilities still add up to $1$; the algebra works out.

Comment: @Brian I agree, I can see if one were to add the two identies they add up to one, however when I went down another path, I think I may have stuffed up...  http://www.texpaste.com/n/bqp06ene